# What's the proper syntax to set a Powershell filter variable based on multiple values?

Tags: syntax, global-variables, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell Script that processes files in a directory based on selection criteria. For one run, I need to act on all HTML files, so I'm using the following code.

```
$bkppath = "\\filepath"
$selectionFilter = "*.htm*"  
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $bkpPath -filter $selectionFilter

ForEach($doc in $srcfiles) {
     do-stuff
}
```

For another run, I need to act on anything that's not *related to* the HTML in the directory, so I want to EXCLUDE `*.htm*`, `*.js`, `*.ico` and `*.xml`. I've not been able to find the proper syntax for applying those multiple values to my `selectionFilter` variable.

I need something like this:

```
$selectionFilter = !("*.htm*" or ".js" or "*.xml" or "*.ico")
```

or

```
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $bkpPath -filter !("*.htm*" or ".js" or "*.xml" or "*.ico")
```

both of which give me a syntax error.

I've not been able to find anything on MSDN that covers how to handle multiple values like this. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not use the `-exclude` parameter of `get-childitem` for the other run?

Comment: `-exclude` would work as well...but my problem is that I can't find an example of the proper syntax for applying the *multiple* values to the parameter. I can `-exclude "*.ico"`, for instance, but don't know the proper syntax to `-exclude ("*.ico" or "*.js")`

Comment: `-exclude *.ico, *.js,*.xml` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `-exclude *.ico, *.js, *xml` is to correct syntax for the exclusion, an important caveat is that the pathname to which the exclusion is applied MUST end with `\*` in order for this to work. `-filter` does not have this requirement; and that's where I was getting messed up.

`$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $bkpPath\* -exclude *.htm*, *.js, *.xml, *.ico` would be the proper syntax in my example.